# Trying to make a List of totals

Tags: dart, flutter

So I have two lists that I each mapped to get the ints, and then I used a reduce function to total them.

I now need just both those totals in a new list, like a totalsList made up of TotalsEntry's or something.

How can this be done?

```
List<int> listOfOnlyPrices = [];
List<int> listOfOnlyExpenses = [];
int totalSales;
int totalExpenses;


void totalSalesWidget() {
 listOfOnlyPrices = items.map<int>((SaleEntry int) => 
 int.price).toList();
 totalSales = listOfOnlyPrices.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
}

void totalExpensesWidget() {
  listOfOnlyExpenses =  expenseList.map<int>((ExpenseEntry int) => int.priceEx).toList();
  totalExpenses = listOfOnlyExpenses.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
}
```

All of this works fine btw. I can use totalSales and totalExpenses already within the app.

Comment: I am afraid to say that I do not quite get what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to have a list that only has two elements, i.e. the integer value of `totalSales` and `totalExpenses`?

Comment: :) Yes that is it, I need a list with two elements,  i.e. the integer value of totalSales and totalExpenses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the following should already do the job:

```
List<int> get totalsList => [totalSales, totalExpenses];
```

Comment: !!!! Thank you.   This is for my mission to learn how make a flutter animated pie chart reactive. The example I had of the chart just had hardcoded data so I made a few lists and now going for making those totals work as the chart data :)

Comment: If this really did answer you question, you can mark it as accepted using the tick mark in order to show others that it solved the problem.